# Gulp concat many files is slow

Tags: performance, gulp, gulp-concat

So i have a gulp config that concats all my angular files into one.
Here is the relevant bits in question

```
const jsPaths = [
  'src/js/**/*.js', // no more than 100 files
  'node_modules/angular-google-places-autocomplete/src/autocomplete.js',
  'node_modules/angular-foundation-6/dist/angular-foundation.js',
  'node_modules/angular-slugify/angular-slugify.js',
  'node_modules/satellizer/satellizer.js',
  'node_modules/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js',
  'node_modules/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js'
]

gulp.task('jsbundle', function(done){
  jsbundle(done)
})

gulp.task('js', ['jsbundle'], function(){
  transpileJs()
})

function jsbundle(done){
  gulp.src(jsPaths)
  .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'))
  .on('end', function() {
    done();
  });
}
```

`Finished 'jsbundle' after 5.04 s`
The finished file is about 1.5mb
Is there anything i can do to speed this up?

Comment: 1.5mb is a huge JS file. Can you load those vendor scripts from a CDN instead?

Comment: its only that large because its un minified. And i think i found a way around it. ill post my findings when i finish tinkering

Answer (score -1):

You can easily minify it with uglify.
Start by installing uglify and rename:

```
npm install -rename gulp-uglify --save-dev
```

And add:

```
`function jsbundle(done){
     gulp.src(jsPaths)
    .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'))
    .pipe(rename('concat.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
   .on('end', function() {
       done();
   });
}`
```